# What does "ento" mean in the context of Clang Static Analyzer?

Tags: clang-static-analyzer

I've been skimming through the source code of Clang Static Analyzer and found a namespace termed `ento`. I'm still wondering what does it mean? Is this an acronym?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this discussion](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/analyzer-Spell-out-ENTO-in-clang-ento-td4068268.html), *ento* is an abbreviation of [entomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomology). It is a joke/pun on bugs:

> It is a joke. It abbreviates entomology. [1]
>
> [1]: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomology

and

> I think this rather an allusion that this stuff supposed to find bugs.

See also https://llvm.org/docs/Lexicon.html:

> This namespace houses the Clang Static Analyzer. It is an abbreviaton
> of entomology.
>
> > “Entomology is the scientific study of insects.”
>
> In the past, this namespace had not only the name GR (aka. Graph
> Reachability) but also entoSA.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the lexicon link. Wasn't aware of that.